# Ruby: Range is empty, but slicing with it produces elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, range, slice

I'm learning Ruby and have just gotten into some stuff about arrays and ranges. I've run into something about slices that, while it makes sense at first glance, confuses me a bit when I look deeper into it.

[IRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) says that `(2..-1).to_a` is an empty array, meaning no values in the range, right?
But if I use that same range in `[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e][2..-1]`, I get back `[:c, :d, :e]` rather than an empty array.

Now, I'm aware that -1 represents the last element of the array, so it kind of makes sense that what got picked, did. But if the range itself would be empty, how is it selecting anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a fascinating question. The answer is that it's not the individual elements of the range that are inspected when slicing the array, but the `first` and `last` elements. Specifically:

```
>> (2..-1).to_a
=> []
>> (2..-1).first
=> 2
>> (2..-1).last
=> -1
```

Thus the example works, since it slices the array from the `[2]` element to the `[-1]` element.

If you want a consistent way to think about this, consider that `(2..-1).to_a` outputs the integers found between `2` and `-1` (of which there are none), but that `[2..-1]` means from the `2` *index* to the `-1` *index*.

(Source: `array.c` and `range.c` in the Ruby source.)

And, the complicated bonus part: to get the meaning you were thinking about, you could use

```
>> [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e].values_at *(2..-1).to_a
=> []
```

Comment: For future reference, what's the star in `*(2..-1).to_a` for?

Comment: that would be the 'splat' operator.

Comment: More precisely: `foo([1,2,3])` calls `foo` with one (list) argument. `foo(*[1,2,3])` calls it with three: it is equivalent to `foo(1,2,3)`; the list is deconstructed and its elements splattered over the function call.

Answer (score 3):

In the slicing operation it's not seeing the range as a `Range` per se, it's just looking at the values of the endpoints, in this case `2` and `-1`. Since `-1` has a special meaning (i.e last item in the list) it just returns everything from item at index `2` to the end of the list. Don't think of it as a `Range` here, just think of it as a convenient way of passing in two numbers (expressing two end points).

Answer (score 1):

The `Array#[]` method does not use the range as a range (that is, it does not call `include?` on it or anything like that); it just takes the two numbers out of it and checks whether it's exclusive.

You can imagine it to look somewhat like this (though the real `[]` is implemented in C, not in [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), and of course also handles arguments other than ranges):

```
def [](range)
  start = range.begin
  length = range.end - start
  length -= 1 if range.exclude_end?
  slice(start, length)
end
```